# Click to Call with a Span line

Tags: javascript

How can I make this a code into 'click to call' while leaving the text format alone, if viewed on a mobile browser?

```
<p class="lplh-29">
    <span style="color:#3c3c3c;">
        <span style="font-size: 22px;">
            <span style="font-family: roboto;">777.111.1234</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Not sure what You mean. Can you explain problem more ?

Comment: This was the line of code on the page, to represent a phone number. But i want to be able to turn it into a "click to call" if it's being viewed on mobile. I hope that clarifies it. I want it to prompt a mobile web browser to call the number.

Comment: You could do that with jQuery mobile with 'tel:' http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a2/docs/pages/link-formats.html

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p class="lplh-29">
    <span style="color:#3c3c3c;">
        <span style="font-size: 22px;">
            <span style="font-family: roboto;">
                <a href="tel:777.111.1234">777.111.1234<a/>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

> If you prefer wrap everything with an anchor tag

```
<a href="tel:777.111.1234" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <p class="lplh-29">
        <span style="color:#3c3c3c;">
            <span style="font-size: 22px;">
                <span style="font-family: roboto;">
                    777.111.1234
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>
<a/>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get rid of the blue underline?

Comment: Yes. Use Css :

a{
 text-decoration: none;
} or inline css: style="text-decoration: none;"